# Google API to download a file from Google Docs as pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-docs

I have a file with some text and tables in my Google Docs. The content of this file is manually updated time to time.

I would need to send out this file as pdf many times a month. It is being done manually with the Web UI (File - Download - pdf) and then sent via Email to my users.

I would like to eliminate this human intervention and create a API which downloads this pdf and provide the endpoint to my users.

Can this use case be done with Google API (preferably JavaScript)? If so, how?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To download the Google Doc to PDF, you can take as base the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#download_a_document) in Google Developers, which use the [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) method to download the file as a PDF. Here is the sample:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

/* Class to demonstrate use-case of drive's export pdf. */
public class ExportPdf {

    /**
     * Download a Document file in PDF format.
     * @param realFileId file ID of any workspace document format file.
     * @return byte array stream if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
     * @throws IOException if service account credentials file not found.
     */
    private static ByteArrayOutputStream exportPdf(String realFileId) throws IOException{
        // Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
        // TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity for
        // guides on implementing OAuth2 for your application.
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(
                credentials);

        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                requestInitializer)
                .setApplicationName("Drive samples")
                .build();

        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            service.files().export(realFileId, "application/pdf")
                    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);

            return (ByteArrayOutputStream) outputStream;
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
            System.err.println("Unable to export file: " + e.getDetails());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to send the email with the attachment automatically, you can use as base the Google Developer Guide to [create messages with attachments](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages_with_attachments), and once the message is created, you can adapt the sample code for [sending messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#sending_messages).

All the guides have samples in Java. If you click on the option "View on GitHub," you will be redirected to a GitHub with the online repository of the code.

** Reference: **

- [Download a Google Workspace Document.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#download_a_document)
- [Files: export.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)
- [Creating messages with attachments.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages_with_attachments)
- [Method: users.drafts.send.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/send)
- [Method: users.messages.send.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the requisite packages & `import`s/`require`s and assuming you have the security code, e.g., an `authorize()` function and friends, a Google Docs `FILENAME`, and a `const MIMETYPE = 'application/pdf'` already, below is the core piece of functionality for Node.js that exports a Google Docs document as PDF and saves it locally:

```
async function exportDocAsPDF(authClient) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authClient});
  let res = await drive.files.list({
    q: `name="${FILENAME}"`,
    fields: 'files(id)',
    pageSize: 1
  });
  const file = res.data.files[0];
  console.log(`** Downloading '${FILENAME}'`);
  const destPath = path.join(process.cwd(), `${FILENAME}.pdf`);
  const fh = await fs.open(destPath, 'w');
  const dest = fh.createWriteStream();
  res = await drive.files.export({
    fileId: file.id,
    mimeType: MIMETYPE,
  }, {responseType: 'stream'});
  await res.data.pipe(dest);
}

authorize().then(exportDocAsPDF).catch(console.error);
```

I wrote about this topic in a [blog post](https://dev.to/wescpy/export-google-docs-as-pdf-without-the-docs-api-9o4) that features versions in both Node.js and Python (2 & 3). The example above is the CommonJS version, but a modern JS ECMAscript module is also available in the post. (For Python users, there are also 2 versions, one using the current auth libraries and another for those who depend on the older, deprecated `oauth2client` library.) For bug fixes and updates, check out the latest version of [all 4 examples in their repo](https://github.com/wescpy/google/tree/main/apps/export-doc-pdf).

To learn more about the Drive API, I created a [set of videos](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/videos) to help developers learn how to use it. If you want to send emails, consider the Gmail API. I don't have a snippet here but have put together another [collection of videos](http://developers.google.com/gmail/videos) covering *that* API. That said, the examples in the video are mostly Python, so if you don't do that, just pretend it's pseudocode because Node.js versions will be quite similar.